# Android application execution

Tags: android, emulation

I am executing an Android chat application on my Windows 7 PC (not using Eclipse). I created one emulator in AVD manager and installed that application using ADB.

I want to know how to run that application in two Android virtual devices simultaneously.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type:

```
adb devices
```

you'll see for ex:

```
emulator-5555
emulator-5554
```

To install your app on each one:

```
adb -s emulator-5555 install yourapp.apk
adb -s emulator-5554 install yourapp.apk
```

Comment: what tha mistake i have done is just launch the AVD and install my application using ADB without specifying option and all, thanks for your valuable answer